# How to reduce the size of values in specific features in a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset taken from UCI [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heterogeneity+Activity+Recognition) that looks like this:

```
    Arrival_Time        Creation_Time         x         y         z  
0  1424696633909  1424696631918283972 -5.952240  0.670212  8.136536   
1  1424696633918  1424696631923288855 -5.995087  0.653549  8.204376   
2  1424696633919  1424696631928385290 -5.942718  0.676163  8.128204   
3  1424696633929  1424696631933420691 -5.991516  0.641647  8.135345   
4  1424696633929  1424696631938456091 -5.965332  0.629745  8.128204   
5  1424696633938  1424696631943522009 -5.991516  0.635696  8.162720   
6  1424696633939  1424696631948496374 -5.915344  0.630936  8.105591   
7  1424696633951  1424696631953592810 -5.984375  0.694016  8.067505   
8  1424696633952  1424696631960428747 -5.937958  0.715439  8.090118   
9  1424696633959  1424696631963663611 -5.902252  0.667831  8.069885
```

As you notice, the values of `Arrival_Time` and `Creation_Time` columns are very huge (Most likely because there are collected from smart watch sensors). I am planning to use neural network for classification but I feel these large values will crush the memory! As an intermediate leaner in preprocessing, what would be the best way to reduce the size of values in these two columns? I thought about normalization but I am not sure if I should apply normalization for ALL features in the dataset to maintain the consistency. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The large values won't crush your memory (all numbers are roughly the same size, but you should pass them through a `MinMaxScaler` first anyway for better conditioning.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: As @Anony-Mousse said in his answer, these look like timestamps, so you should treat them into time series. You can extract dates from it, date of month, day of week, and such things, which may positively effect your model.

Answer (score 2):

Do not ignore the **meaning** of attributes.

These are **timestamps**. You need to treat this data set as a time series. Time is not the same thing as x,y,z coordinates.